# How to detect if keyboard is present in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to know if the keyboard is present when the button is pressed. How would I do this? I have tried but I don't have any luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Using this protocol, `KeyboardReadable`, you can conform to any `View` and get keyboard updates from it.

`KeyboardReadable` protocol:

```
import Combine
import UIKit


/// Publisher to read keyboard changes.
protocol KeyboardReadable {
    var keyboardPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> { get }
}

extension KeyboardReadable {
    var keyboardPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        Publishers.Merge(
            NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
                .map { _ in true },
            
            NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
                .map { _ in false }
        )
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

It works by using Combine and creating a publisher so we can receive the keyboard notifications.

With an example view of how it can be applied:

```
struct ContentView: View, KeyboardReadable {
    
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var isKeyboardVisible = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Text", text: $text)
            .onReceive(keyboardPublisher) { newIsKeyboardVisible in
                print("Is keyboard visible? ", newIsKeyboardVisible)
                isKeyboardVisible = newIsKeyboardVisible
            }
    }
}
```

You can now read from the `isKeyboardVisible` variable to know if the keyboard is visible.

When the `TextField` is active with the keyboard showing, the following prints:

> Is keyboard visible?  true

When the keyboard is then hidden upon hitting return, the following prints instead:

> Is keyboard visible?  false

You can use `keyboardWillShowNotification`/`keyboardWillHideNotification` to update as soon as they keyboard starts to appear or disappear, and the `keyboardDidShowNotification`/`keyboardDidHideNotification` variants to update after the keyboard has appeared or disappeared. I prefer the `will` variant because the updates are instant for when the keyboard shows.

Comment: To be strict you should use DidShow/DidHide notifications for PO question, because Will* variants are posted *before* asked state. Sometimes it is important.

Comment: @Asperi Good point - I have added that now, thanks! I typically prefer the `will` variant because the updates are instantly, whereas the `did` variant you have to wait for the whole appearing/disappearing animation.

Comment: This is a really clever answer. I try and think of ways to use Combine and I would never have thought of this. But I am clever enough to capitalise on it!

Answer (score 27):

My little improvement @George's answer.

Implement publisher right inside the View protocol

```
import Combine

extension View {

  var keyboardPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    Publishers
      .Merge(
        NotificationCenter
          .default
          .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
          .map { _ in true },
        NotificationCenter
          .default
          .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
          .map { _ in false })
      .debounce(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

I also added debounce operator in order to prevent true - false toggle when you have multiple TextFields and user moves between them.

Use in any View

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
  @State var isKeyboardPresented = false
  @State var firstTextField = ""
  @State var secondTextField = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("First textField", text: $firstTextField)
      TextField("Second textField", text: $secondTextField)
    }
    .onReceive(keyboardPublisher) { value in
      isKeyboardPresented = value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wait, what, tab indents are set to 2?  You go Max, stick it to them!  (I have refused to set my tabs to anything else but 2 since the eighties :-)

Answer (score 15):

### iOS 15:

You can use the `focused(_:)` view modifier and `@FocusState` property wrapper to know whether a text field is editing, and also change the editing state.

```
@State private var text: String = ""
@FocusState private var isTextFieldFocused: Bool

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("hello", text: $text)
            .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
        
        if isTextFieldFocused {
            Button("Keyboard is up!") {
                isTextFieldFocused = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Focus and keyboard presence are not necessarily the same thing. If there is an external keyboard connected, this will not show the right result, in terms of keyboard presence.

Answer (score 13):

**With Environment Key...**

Taking @Lepidopteron's answer, but using it to drive an environment key.

This allows you to access the keyboard state in any view using

```
@Environment(\.keyboardShowing) var keyboardShowing
```

All you have to do is add a view modifier at the top of your hierarchy

```
RootView()
.addKeyboardVisibilityToEnvironment()
```

This is all powered by the following ViewModifier file...

```
public extension View {
    
    /// Sets an environment value for keyboardShowing
    /// Access this in any child view with
    /// @Environment(\.keyboardShowing) var keyboardShowing
    func addKeyboardVisibilityToEnvironment() -> some View {
        modifier(KeyboardVisibility())
    }
}

private struct KeyboardShowingEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = false
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var keyboardShowing: Bool {
        get { self[KeyboardShowingEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[KeyboardShowingEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

private struct KeyboardVisibility:ViewModifier {
    
#if os(macOS)
    
    fileprivate func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .environment(\.keyboardShowing, false)
    }
    
#else
    
    @State var isKeyboardShowing:Bool = false
    
    private var keyboardPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        Publishers
            .Merge(
                NotificationCenter
                    .default
                    .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
                    .map { _ in true },
                NotificationCenter
                    .default
                    .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
                    .map { _ in false })
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    fileprivate func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .environment(\.keyboardShowing, isKeyboardShowing)
            .onReceive(keyboardPublisher) { value in
                isKeyboardShowing = value
            }
    }
    
#endif
}
```

Comment: This is so simple...many thanks to you. For beginners (like me), make sure you add `import SwiftUI` and `import Combine` to the top of your file. I added `.addKeyboardVisibilityToEnvironment()` to the first calling of `ContentView()` in my initial `WindowGroup` and `@Environment(\.keyboardShowing) var keyboardShowing` to the top of my `ContentView` view. Everything works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: I found this  https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/436070583?utm_id=0 use AnyCancellable , is the best aproach?

Comment: This should be the right solution.
We can not use above `.onReceive(keyboardPublisher)` solution. It does not catch the initial event value but only change event. For example, if you have a list of views with a filter function, and you put `.onReceive(keyboardPublisher)` into each list item, then you will get into problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could also create a viewModifier to get notified of Keyboard notifications.

```
struct OnkeyboardAppearHandler: ViewModifier {
    var handler: (Bool) -> Void
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
                    handler(true)
                }
                
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
                    handler(false)
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    public func onKeyboardAppear(handler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(OnkeyboardAppearHandler(handler: handler))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified from @Confused_Vorlon, Change `AnyPublisher` to `AnyCancellable`, best aproach, good practice to avoid memory leak.

### Code

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

public extension View {
    
    /// Sets an environment value for keyboardShowing
    /// Access this in any child view with
    /// @Environment(\.keyboardShowing) var keyboardShowing
    func addKeyboardVisibilityToEnvironment() -> some View {
        modifier(KeyboardVisibility())
    }
}

private struct KeyboardShowingEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = false
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var keyboardShowing: Bool {
        get { self[KeyboardShowingEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[KeyboardShowingEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

private final class KeyboardMonitor: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isKeyboardShowing: Bool = false
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        #if os(macOS)
        // No es necesario hacer nada para macOS
        #else
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
            .map { _ in true }
            .assign(to: \.isKeyboardShowing, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
            .map { _ in false }
            .assign(to: \.isKeyboardShowing, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        #endif
    }
}

private struct KeyboardVisibility: ViewModifier {
    @StateObject private var keyboardMonitor = KeyboardMonitor()
    
    fileprivate func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .environment(\.keyboardShowing, keyboardMonitor.isKeyboardShowing)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```swift
App
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
    .addKeyboardVisibilityToEnvironment()


View

@Environment(\.keyboardShowing) var keyboardShowing
...
Text("Keyboard present: \(keyboardShowing.description)" )
```

### Test

Test in MacOs and simulator iphone15 pro, XCode 15